# Add New Textbox to Userform or Sheet when the existing is filled

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I have been using vba for a while but I am stuck with this problem:

I would like to add a new Textbox to an existing Userform or Sheet whenever the existing textbox is filled. 
Look at the image below to have a better idea of what I intent to do.

- In the first image, below "Selected Indices" there is only one index
  filled, namely "ER01" and below you can read "Enter Index"
- Moving the next image you can see that I filled the second textbox
  with "ER02" and automatically, after pressing enter, the textbox with
  "Enter Index" appears.
- The same thing happens for the third image where I filled the third
  textbox with "ER03" and automatically, after pressing enter, the
  textbox with "Enter Index" appears

[image: EXAMPLE]

I hope I have been clear enough

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Can you post your existing code please.  So can see what it's based around.  Thanks

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but there is not an existing code since the starting point would be a userform  or a sheet with a single textbox in it.

Comment: So you haven't tried anything yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a good start for you.  Place the this script in a clean regular module.  It will create a textbox (named MyTB) on Sheet1 with the text "hello" in it. (Source: http://www.contextures.com/excelvbatextboxcreate.html)

```
Sub AddTextBox()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim oTB As Object
Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
   Set oTB = ws.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.TextBox.1")
    With oTB
    .Name = "MyTB"
'    .LinkedCell = "$A$2"
    .Left = ws.Range("B2").Left
    .Top = ws.Range("B2").Left
    .Width = ws.Range("B2").Width
    .Height = ws.Range("B2").Height
    .Object.BackColor = RGB(204, 204, 255)
    .Object.ForeColor = RGB(0, 0, 255)
    .Object.Text = "Hello"
    End With
End Sub
```

After you have created the textbox on Sheet1, place the following code in the Sheet1 module.

```
Private Sub MyTB_Change()
If MyTB.Text = 21 Then Beep
End Sub
```

Then go to Sheet1 and change the "Hello" in the textbox to the number 21.  It should beep.

These are all the skills you need to do what you want to.  All you need to do is add the logic.  Instead of beeping when you enter 21 into MyTB, you can direct it to another subroutine that creates a second textbox.  Always remember that this is a learning website, not a coding website.  And you can dynamically add code to the sheet module for that second textbox as well, and on and on for as many textboxes as you need.

Comment: that is a good start!!! thank you very much for the time you spent to answer my question. I wonder If something like that is possible using userform too: basically using MyTB_Change() to change the dimensions of the userform anytime that a new textbox is added. Any way thank you again

Comment: yes, you can add form items to a form while running the form.  This type of programming is often called "on the fly" since it can create or change elements during operation.  If you google the following you should get a few dozen good websites to learn from.  vba excel add form elements on the fly programmatically